# How to control the volume of raspberry pi with python 3?

Tags: raspberry-pi, volume

I have been looking up the web for any reference to control the volume of raspberry pi (b+) with python script . I come up with [this thread previously asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41592431/changing-volume-in-python-program-on-raspbery-pi) but python-alsaaudio doesn't works with python 3 or say in the thonny python idle . 
So I need to know any correct way to change the volume of pi as per the user input .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way is to control volume through a command line tool. There is a tool for the Alsa command line called `amixer`:

```
amixer sset Master 50%
```

Now you can create a simple python script that runs the above command:

```
import subprocess


# a value between 0 and 100
volume = 50
command = ["amixer", "sset", "Master", "{}%".format(volume)]
subprocess.Popen(command)
```

You can change `Master` to other soundcards. You can get a list of controls:

```
$ amixer scontrols

Simple mixer control 'Master',0
Simple mixer control 'PCM',0
Simple mixer control 'Line',0
Simple mixer control 'CD',0
Simple mixer control 'Mic',0
Simple mixer control 'Mic Boost (+20dB)',0
Simple mixer control 'Video',0
Simple mixer control 'Phone',0
Simple mixer control 'IEC958',0
Simple mixer control 'Aux',0
Simple mixer control 'Capture',0
Simple mixer control 'Mix',0
Simple mixer control 'Mix Mono',0
```

Comment: i tried above command in the terminal but it throws errord saying`i@raspberrypi:~ $ amixer sset Master 50%
amixer: Unable to find simple control 'Master',0

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ amixer sset PCM 50%
amixer: Unable to find simple control 'PCM',0

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ amixer sset USB 50%
amixer: Unable to find simple control 'USB',0
`  I also tried to change the soundcards to PCM but the issue was same.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It works now . actually when I ran `amixer scontrols` there was neither `Master` nor ~PCM~ . I came to know to select which controller one from list I got [`Simple mixer control 'Speaker',0
Simple mixer control 'Mic',0
Simple mixer control 'Auto Gain Control',0
`]  with above command. So in my case I used Speaker. Thanks!!

Comment: There is one question! Is there any way or command to get the current volume of raspberry pi ? So that i can fetch through my python script.

Comment: `amixer get Master` would print result, you can do the same process to read it with your py script.

Comment: Thanks i got it !!